# Trigonometry calculate tilt angle from accelerometer data

Tags: javascript, trigonometry, accelerometer, angle, tilt

I have the following Figure and the equations:

[Three Axis for measuring tilt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2WHr9.png)

[Equations for measuring tilt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fym4I.png)

The body on the Figures is a tri-axial accelerometer sensor, which measures accelaration in meters/seconds².

The goal is to calculate the tilt of the following angles using acceleration values:

- ρ: angle of the X-axis relative to the ground (orange line);
- Φ: angle of the Y-axis relative to the ground (orange line);
- θ: angle of the Z-axis relative to the gravity (green line).

Could someone explain how to find equations 1,2 and 3 from the figure above?

Source of the equations and figure: https://www.thierry-lequeu.fr/data/AN3461.pdf

There is another similar and more detailed source that uses the same equations, but I also could not understand how to find them: https://www.analog.com/en/app-notes/an-1057.html

I have already implemented them and it is working, I just want help to understand how to obtain the equations. Here is the code:

```
let pitch = Math.atan(ax / Math.sqrt((Math.pow(ay,2) + Math.pow(az,2))) );
let roll = Math.atan(ay / Math.sqrt((Math.pow(ax,2) + Math.pow(az,2))) );
let theta = Math.atan(Math.sqrt((Math.pow(ax,2) + Math.pow(ay,2))) /az);
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

This is the Pythagorean theorem, finding the 2D distance between 0,0 and a point represented by the two numbers given. If we assign that to a new function it may be clearer:

```
distance(a, b) { return sqrt((pow(a,2) + pow(b,2))) }
```

Then angles are calculated by using the inverse tangent function with a distance from that function representing one side of the triangle. For example, the pitch in your question divides the x acceleration by the distance between 0,0 and the acceleration in the YZ plane.

```
pitch = atan(x / distance(y, z))
```